# How to use the current value of a variable in Python in another class without using arguments in the method

Tags: python

I have the 2 python classes:

**Test.py**

```
import Test2
variable1_Test = 1


#Call function from Test2
if __name__ == "__main__":
    variable1_Test = 5
    Test2.print_variables()
```

**Test2.py**

```
def print_variables ():
    import Test
    print(f"Test.variable1_Test: {Test.variable1_Test}")
```

Strangely, when I run the main code in Test.py (which should be the class for the main execution) the output of `variable1_Test` is 1 and not 5, altough I clearly upadted its value to 5 before calling the method `Test2.print_variables()`.

So my question is why this is happening and Python does not see the updated variable? Further, I would like to know how to use the current value of a variable in Python in another class without using arguments in the method. I know a work around is to pass arguments to the method `print_variables` in Test2.py. But I don't want to do this as I have a big simulation with over 100 parameters that I would have to pass. So I just want to change certain parameters in Test.py and then run the method in Test2.py with updated variables. How can I do that?

Comment: When you do `import Test`, everything in `Test.py` is executed, including the `variable1_Test = 1` line.  It's much less confusing to pass state via arguments (it doesn't need to be 100 individual arguments, put them all in a `@dataclass` or similar).

Comment: When importing the main script it is seen as a separate module (with the same code but own namespace and variables) but the part after the `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard isn't executed because the imported module is not (seen as) the main script.

Comment: @Samwise: Thanks Samwise for your comment. Still I don't understand why Python does not see the updated variables. It is really strange for me. The updated of the variable does not have any effect. Further, I dont want to pass more than 100 arguemtns into a method or define them every time I neeed to call this method. is there not a convenient way of telling python to use the current values of the variables and not the old ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Circular dependencies should generally be avoided.  One reason to avoid them is that the semantics are confusing -- the `Test` namespace inside your `Test2` code is not the same as the global namespace in your main script.

Although your question asked how to do this without arguments, the best way to do this is by passing the data as an argument so you don't have a circular dependency and can be assured that you're passing in the exact data from one module to another that you intend to.

Change `Test2.py` to:

```
def print_variables(variables):
    print(f"variable one_test: {variables['one_test']}")
```

and `Test.py` to:

```
import Test2

variables = {
    'one_test': 1
}

#Call function from Test2
if __name__ == "__main__":
    variables['one_test'] = 5
    Test2.print_variables(variables)
```

and you will get the desired output.

You can add a hundred values to the `variables` dict, and you can change them individually (the same way you'd change individual variables in the global namespace), and you will not need to add a hundred arguments to the `print_variables` function.  Passing the dict in as an argument means you can pass the actual dict into the function rather than requiring the function to circularly import the main module.

Comment: Thanks a lot Samwise for your answer. I really appreciate it. I still don't understand why Python is not seeing the updated version of the variable. This is extremely weird for me (the update does not have any effect; so why is it then possible to do this update?). Is there no option to "force" Python to use the latest version of the variable? Regarding your workaround solution: Can I also use this when not only having primitive data types like integers or booleans but also complex objects?

Comment: It's not about the "latest version", there are actually two different variables (a `__main__.variable1_Test` and a `Test2.Test1.variable1_Test`).  And yes, you can put anything you want into a dict.

Comment: Thanks Samwise for your answer, I really appreciate it. It helped. I upvoted and accepted your answer.